# Apache 2.4 + React Router 4 always routing to my 404 page component

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router, create-react-app

I'm having trouble getting my create react app build to properly route to my components on my server.

I have a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

so that it always routes to my index.html

the url to my site is .com/project and my homepage option in my package.json file is `homepage: '/project'`

I have ran out of things to do.

Because of my htaccess it's always routing to my index.html but the router is always loading the 404 component. What am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occured because the base routing was wrong so it was constitently routing to the 404 page.

Setting the `<Router basename="/<Directory>">` and adding the homepage option to my package.json file fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?$1 [L,QSA]
```